# What is the French  card game Paquet Voleur called in English?

Tags: identify-this-game

In Quebec, Canada, we have a card game called *Paquet Voleur*. This roughly translates to *pile thief*. Basically, each player has cards in his hand and there are cards on the table. The goal is to make pairs of cards with one card from your hand and one card on the table. You then put that pair, face up, in your "pile". The twist is that people can make pairs with the top card on your pile and take your whole pile.

Does this game solely exist in Quebec? I'm trying to find the English name for it if not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Stealing Bundles](http://www.pagat.com/fishing/bundle.html)